# Monitor XHR requests on Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I can easily monitor and modify navigator.sendBeacon requests with a code like this.

```
if(navigator.sendBeacon && navigator.sendBeacon.toString().indexOf('native code') !== -1){                    
    try {
        var proxied = window.navigator.sendBeacon;            
        window.navigator.sendBeacon = function() {
            // Make an arguments copy
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var _this = this;
            
            // ...
            // MAKE MODIFICATIONS TO THE REQUEST
            // ...

            // Send modified request
            proxied.apply(_this, args);                                  
            
            // Send the original request
            return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        ;
    } catch (e) {
        // In case something goes wrong, let's apply back the arguments to the original function
        return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
    }        
}
```

How to do something similar for all XHR requests?